# Caption of an included PDF is not showing up

Tags: floats, captions

I'm a bit new to LaTeX and I wanted to include a PDF image as a figure like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{pic.pdf}   
    \caption{Some Text
    }
    \label{fig:someLabel}
\end{figure}
```

However, the caption is not showing. It works however if I use PNG or JPG. 
The reason why I use PDF is the image quality that drops severly when using PNG or JPG on top of the bad export quality of the program I use to create these images.

So what can I do to display the image in good quality, on the page I need it to with the caption I wrote?

The head of the document (document class and packages) is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% own latex packages

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{balance}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}

\usepackage{array} % for defining a new column type
\usepackage{varwidth} %for the varwidth minipage environment
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
% recommended: uncomment following line if you write in German 
%\usepackeage{german}  
\makeglossaries
\input{glossary.tex}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\parskip = \medskipamount
\frenchspacing
\bibpunct[; ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{;}
...
\input{image.tex}
```

Note: This is a template from my university, so I probably can only add or remove my own packages. The image is defined in a separate file and inserted at some point in the text.

The rest of the document is made of sections, file inputs, bibliography and glossary. There shouldn't be anything too exotic.

If you need more info please feel free to ask, but I don't know for what information to look for to fix this.

The PDF I try to include is a single picture on a single page. It is an export of draw.io (https://draw.io/).

Comment: It should work with pdf like with png, unless your pdf-file or your code is doing something curious. Make a real, complete example and make the pdf available somewhere.

Comment: I added the packages I used. Don't think uploading the whole thesis here is a good idea. I'm a bit new to latex so I don't know exactly what is needed to solve this problem.

Comment: What is needed is a *small* but *complete* example that can be compiled as a test. I don't have *any* time to complete or reduce your example or hunt down files or to write long explanations what I could need to reproduce your problem. Use your brain or search this site, there should be enough hits for minimal examples.

Comment: Well if you dont have time, then why bother? As I said I'm new to latex and am using TexStudio to simply write and add a simple picture in an acceptable quality. It didnt work so I came here to ask if anyone knows more. I will try making the example you asked, but if you dont have time, dont bother.

Comment: Besides, this is a template provided by the university, so it might not be that easy to make a simple small complete example.

Comment: If you had provided a sensible example that I could used for a fast test I would have checked if there is a obvious solution, but I don't have the time for long test preparations.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the PDF I used, was a full page with a lot of whitespace at the bottom, which caused LaTeX to not display the caption.

After making sure the image of the PDF is not covering the whole page the issue was resolved.

It was a little unexpected that no warning indicated that the caption is not displaying because of the size of the PDF.

Comment: From the information of the question I would have expected two warnings `LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by ...` and ```LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.```